# Nginx content-type with proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, node.js

I currently use:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server_tokens off;

    upstream webapp {
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://webapp;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_hide_header Content-Type;
        }
    }
}
```

The upstream is a nodejs app that serves a bunch of .js files, since none of them have content-type it causes the client-side error `Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`.

I have tried to remove the proxy header with hopes that content-type will be added automatically by nginx-proxy from mime.types (which exist).

Comment: Fix upstream app to send content type

Comment: Or better configure nginx to serve static files

Comment: @AlexeyTen I see that when a curl and print headers the upstream does indeed send the content-type, I shall try to pass that header instead of blocking it with proxy_pass_header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved with `proxy_pass_header Content-Type;` no idea why nginx would hide the header.

Comment: It looks like you were intentionally hiding the header with proxy_hide_header Content-Type;

Comment: @JoseLUgia the whole point is that even without `proxy_hide_header Content-Type;` it wouldn't appear, I had to explicitly add `proxy_pass_header Content-Type;` for it to work.